# Bits shifted by bit shifting operators(<<, >>) in C, C++

Tags: c++, c

can we access the bits shifted by bit shifting operators(<<, >>) in C, C++?
For example:
23>>1
can we access the last bit shifted(1 in this case)?

Comment: You'd better use 23&1.

Comment: What's your goal exactly?

Comment: Yes, but not after shifting (in most architectures). If you shift a value right be one, you can use the bitwise AND operator to select the bits that would be shifted off.

Comment: You can only do that by applying another operation on the original value before doing the shift.

Comment: What do you mean by "can we access"? What do you want to do with it? "Access" is extremely vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `23>>1`, the bit `0x01` is purged - you have no way of retrieving it after the bit shift.

That said, nothing's stopping you from checking for the bit *before* shifting:

```
int  value   = 23;
bool bit1    = value & 0x01;
int  shifted = value >> 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the shift operators only give the value after shifting. You'll need to do other bitwise operations to extract the bits that are shifted out of the value; for example:

```
unsigned all_lost  = value & ((1 << shift)-1);  // all bits to be removed by shift
unsigned last_lost = (value >> (shift-1)) & 1;  // last bit to be removed by shift
unsigned remaining = value >> shift;            // lose those bits
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the bits *before* shifting, e.g.

```
value  = 23;          // start with some value
lsbits = value & 1;   // extract the LSB
value >>= 1;          // shift
```

Answer (score 0):

It worth signal that on MSVC compiler an intrinsic function exists: [_bittest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h65k4tze(VS.80).aspx)

that speeds up the operation.